# How was the quadratic formula found and proven?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-history, quadratics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can ALL quadratic equations be solved by the quadratic formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula)
>   [History of Quadratic Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172602/history-of-quadratic-formula)

How was the quadratic formula $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ found and proven?

Comment: Do you mean historically or how to prove it?

Comment: Previously: [History of quadratic formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172602/856) (seems to be answered in the comments), and [Why can ALL quadratic equations be solved by the quadratic formula?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/49229/856)

Comment: ah, thanks for the edit.

Comment: For future reference, when you are adding tags to your question, please read the short descriptions that pop up and make sure they are appropriate. For example, the description for [tag:proof-theory] says "Proof theory is an area of logic that studies proof as formal mathematical objects," which is not what your question is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that [Alkharazmi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu%E1%B8%A5ammad_ibn_M%C5%ABs%C4%81_al-Khw%C4%81rizm%C4%AB) was the first person who found the formula in generla case. Though, he stated it in terms of Arabic words like "Xi", means "thing". How did it find it? [Here](http://www.kcvs.ca/martin/math/math499/projects/alkhwarizmi/contributions%20of%20al-khwarizmi.pdf) is the summery of his work, in our language.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#History   and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticEquation.html

Comment: I don't think that is true.  al-Khwarizmi didn't have a concept of negative numbers, so he treated equations of the form $ax^2 + bx = c$, $ax^2 + c = bx$, and $ax^2 = bx + c$ as separate cases.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know for sure, but I imagine it was first found by thinking about rearranging squares and rectangles, as in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

by completing the square. $a\neq 0$,  $ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x^2+\dfrac{b}{a}x+\dfrac{c}{a}\right)=\cdots$

Comment: This is way too sketchy. Perhaps a little more expanded development would have helped the OP better.

Comment: I doubt that it's true that it was first discovered or proved by completing the square.