# Factorize the differential operator $[D^2-(x^2+1)]$ into two first order linear operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am Trying to factorize the differential operator $[D^2-(x^2+1)]$ into two first order linear operators. But I have not been able to.

I am trying to split it into $[D+A][D-B]f=[D^2-(x^2+1)]f$. But at the end I get a really ugly differential equation that I cannot solve (It should be an easy one).

Is there any hint?

Thanks

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: What I have seen in operator $D$ is $D$ needs to act on a function as $Dy$ not $D\pm y$. Don't you think it is a typo in the question?

Comment: @BabakS. No. It's OK as it stands. One usually thinks about operators such as $x\frac{d}{dx}$ or $\frac{d}{dx}-x$, which are useful.

Comment: it is [D+A][D-B] Where A, B are functions.  The operator is acting in f.

Comment: Hint: what is $D( x \phi(x)) - x D(\phi(x))$ for any function $\phi(x)$?

Comment: the solution that peter suggests does not work

Comment: @Peter Difference of squares formula [requires *commutativity*.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/49298/23500) But $\rm\: D f \!-\! f D = f' = 0 \iff f\,$ is constant, i.e as linear operators, the derivative $\rm\,D\,$ commutes only with constant functions.

Comment: @MathGems Silly me, sure. Could you drop by the chat?

Comment: @MathGems Hehehe, I'd like to ask you a little about Jacobson.

Comment: @MathGems Oh, I don't really have a question, but'd like to discuss stuff. I'll delete the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factorization means, that for any differentiable function $f(x)$, and for some $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ we have:
$$
   (D^2 - (x^2+1)) \circ f(x) = f^{\prime\prime}(x) - (x^2+1) f(x) = \left( D + a(x) \right) \left(D + b(x) \right) \circ f(x)
$$
Start expanding the right-hand-side:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
   \left( D + a(x) \right) \left(D + b(x) \right) \circ f(x) &=& \left( D + a(x) \right)  \circ \left( f^{\prime}(x) + b(x) f(x)\right) \\ &=& f^{\prime\prime}(x) + \left(b(x) f(x)\right)^\prime + a(x) f^\prime(x) + a(x) b(x) f(x) \\
 &=& f^{\prime\prime}(x) + \left( a(x) + b(x) \right) f^\prime(x) + \left( a(x) b(x) + b^\prime(x) \right) f(x)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Since the identity must hold for arbitrary $f(x)$ we should have $a(x) + b(x) = 0$ and $a(x) b(x) + b^\prime(x) = -x^2-1$, giving $a(x) = -b(x) = x$. Thus
$$
  (D^2 - (x^2+1)) = (D + x)( D-x)
$$

Comment: thanks. The las differential equation how do you solve it without inspection?

Comment: @Sasha What are the conditions to find a factorisation for any linear differential operator? thanks for your time