# Solving a simple quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have problems every time I face a quadratic equation. What can I do to learn how to solve them? Can anyone please show me how to solve the one below and explain the basic principle of solving quadratic equations.

$$x^2- xa - ab = 0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a formula:
$$Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x_{1,2} = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}.$$
$A$ is whatever is next to $x^2$, $B$ is whatever is next to $x$, and $C$ is without $x$. In your case:
$$x^2 - xa - ab = 1 \cdot x^2 + (-a)x + (-ab) = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad A = 1, \quad B = -a, \quad C = -ab,$$
so
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4ab}}{2}.$$

Comment: Where does this formula come from?

Comment: It's a well known formula which you can easily check by substituting $x_1$ and $x_2$ for $x$. @JamesMaslek has just give the proper link, so I won't repeat what he wrote.

Comment: the formula is actually derived in a different question on this site

Comment: Here is the question @Zar is talking about: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula

Answer (score 5):

The solution to any quadratic is the well known Quadratic Formula.

$x = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}$ (as @Vedran Sego has).  This comes from [completing the square](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/quadratic-equation-derivation.html)