# Quadratic Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$0 = a(x^2 + \frac ba x) + c = a(x^2 + \frac ba x + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}) -\frac{b^2}{4a} + c$$
$$= a(x + \frac b{2a})^2 + c - \frac{b^2}{4a}$$
It is more than obvious that the above equation simplifies to the Quadratic Formula, yet I was curious as to why the method of simplifying is done as seen above from the original
$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ in that way, for instance how does it become $a(x^2 + \frac bax) + c$?

Comment: Divide the first two terms by $a$.

Comment: "for instance how does it become a(x^2+(b/a)x)+c?"

Comment: There was an [MSE discussion of the quadratic formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula) quite a hile ago that may be interesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

$$ax^2+bx+c=0\tag{1}$$
taking $a$ common from first two terms
$$a\left(x^2 + \frac bax\right) + c=0$$

There's no perfect way of doing something in Mathematics, but we're just interested in interesting ways to do things and I guess that's all Mathematics is all about.