# Solving $3t^2-\frac{12}{3}t+\frac{4}{3}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring

I need to to solve:
$$3t^2-\frac{12}{3}t+\frac{4}{3}=0$$

The solution manual factorizes this to $\dfrac{1}{3}(3t-2)^2$. How can you do this easily?

Comment: Why not use quadratic fomula

Comment: Start multiplying everything by $3$. It looks nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
for $ax^2+bx+c=0$
Stick to $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Interesting thing is, [It always works](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula/49243#49243)!

Comment: Side note: Use $\sqrt{-x} = i\sqrt{x}$ for negative discriminant to obtain the $\mathbb C$-factorisation for an irreducible polynomial (over $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Maybe somebody denies existence of the roots of $x^2+1$.

Comment: I know mate, I just made fun of him/her :)

Answer (score 2):

Take $\dfrac13$ common, to get this -

$\dfrac13\left({9t^2  - 12t + 4}\right)$
Using $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$, we can write the latter bracket as $(3t -2)^2$

Comment: Refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how to use MathJax here.

Comment: @Integrator I didn't vote FYI.

Comment: Yes thank you, I will go to that link right away.

Comment: @Integrator Very funny: The help page features the formula from your answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

A problem like this is easy if you make a substitution, for example.
$$3t^2-\frac{12}{3}t+\frac{4}{3}=0$$
$$\frac{9}{3}t^2-\frac{12}{3}t+\frac{4}{3}=0$$
$$\frac{1}{3}(9t^2-12t+4)=0$$
$$\frac{1}{3}((3t)^2-4(3t)+4)=0$$
Now, let $s=3t$
$$\frac{1}{3}(s^2-4s+4)=0$$
$$\frac{1}{3}(s-2)^2=0$$
Substituting back we have
$$\frac{1}{3}(3t-2)^2=0$$