# not easily factored quadratic expression how to find its roots

Tags: linear-algebra, roots, factoring, quadratics

Could you please help me and explain this issue:

> If a quadratic equation is not easily factored then its roots can be found using *quadratic formula*: If $ax^2+bx+c=0$ ($a\ne0$), then the roots are
>   $$x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \text{ and }x=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
>   These are two distinct real numbers unless $b^2-4ac\le0$. If $b^2-4ac=0$ then these two expressions for $x$ are equal to $-\frac b{2a}$, and the equation has only one root. If $b^2-4ac<0$, then $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is not a real number and the equation has no real roots.

[image]

Is there any secyfic formula for this exist?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question. The image shows the formula for solving quadratic equations. You should also check Vieta's  formulas i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas

Comment: There are very many duplicates of this - for my money the best possible duplicate is [Why can ALL quadratic equations be solved by the quadratic formula?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

take the quadratic equation ($ax^2 + bx + c = 0$)

Divide the quadratic equation by a, which is allowed because a is non-zero:

$$x^2 + \frac{b}{a} x + \frac{c}{a}=0.$$
Subtract $\frac c a$ from both sides of the equation, yielding:

$$x^2 + \frac{b}{a} x= -\frac{c}{a}.$$
The quadratic equation is now in a form to which the method of **completing the square** can be applied. Thus, add a constant to both sides of the equation such that the left hand side becomes a complete square:

$$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\left( \frac{b}{2a} \right)^2 =-\frac{c}{a}+\left( \frac{b}{2a} \right)^2,$$
which produces:

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2=-\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}.$$
Accordingly, after rearranging the terms on the right hand side to have a common denominator, we obtain this:

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}.$$
The square has thus been completed. Taking the square root of both sides yields the following equation:

$$x+\frac{b}{2a}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac\ }}{2a}.$$
Isolating $x$ gives the quadratic formula:

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac\ }}{2a}.$$
The plus-minus symbol "$±$" indicates that both

$$x=\frac{-b + \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}\quad\text{and}\quad x=\frac{-b - \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: If you want your answers read, appreciated and eventually upvoted, you better learn the easy few directions there exist to properly write mathematics in this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference