# Quadratic inequalities 1

Tags: inequality, quadratics

The question is : $2x^2-3x-1 \leq 0$

I've got the answers but I keep getting them wrong.
If someone could write out the steps it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic polynomial $2x^2 - 3x - 1$ has zeroes at $$x=\frac {3±\sqrt{17}}{4}$$

and is concave up. Hence $2x^2 - 3x - 1 \leq 0 \Longleftrightarrow\frac {3-\sqrt{17}}{4} \leq x \leq \frac {3+\sqrt{17}}{4}  $

Comment: I'm having troubles with coming up with the x. Would you be able to show me how you got it?

Comment: This is done by the quadratic formula, which you should have been taught. Otherwise, I refer you here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula One word of advice: sometimes, it's difficult to determine whether or not a given quadratic equation may be factored easily. What you must do is determine whether or not the discriminant, $b^2 - 4ac$, is a perfect square. If it is, it may be possible to factor the expression nicely.