# How can I simplify Po-Shen Loh's method of solving quadratics?

Tags: roots, quadratics

**My question is, is there a way to eliminate the need for fraction arithmetic and rationalizing denominators necessitated by Po-Shen Loh's alternative to the quadratic formula while still being able to provide a student to whom you're teaching the method an intuitive understanding of what is going on?**

[A few months back, Po-Shen Loh published an article providing an alternative to the quadratic formula.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06709) His method applies the properties of quadratics described [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3678600/209963).
For Loh's method to be used, the quadratic must be of the form $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ where $A=1$. Certainly, if $A\neq 1$ you can divide through by $A$ and not affect the roots, but it means fractions, accompanying fraction arithmetic, and the possible need to rationalize denominators--all of which is not necessary if just using the commonly memorized quadratic formula. Consider just trying to solve $3x^2 + 3x + 1 = 0$ using Loh's method and you'll see what I mean. You end up with fractions all the way through with denominators of 2, 3, 4, 6, and 12 at some point in the process.

Comment: You can watch a YouTube video by Grant Sanderson of 3blue1brown about Loh's method here: https://youtu.be/MHXO86wKeDY.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is! We'll just need to perform a dilation on the function by replacing $y$ with $\frac{y}{A}$ and $x$ with $\frac{x}{A}$. The result is a larger scaled version of the parabola with $A$ being the scale factor. You'll just need to divide your answer of $m\pm d$ by $A$.

Notice what this dilation does to the function.

> $\frac{y}{A}=A(\frac{x}{A})^2+B(\frac{x}{A})+C$
>   $y=x^2+Bx+AC$

Now, the new $A$ is $1$, but neither the new $B$ nor the new $C$ are fractions making this quadratic SO much easier to solve! And, once you understand why, you can save time by simply replacing $A$ with $1$, and $C$ with $AC$ rather than going through the whole process.

Furthermore, since $m=\frac{-B}{2}$, you might consider manipulating the function to avoid fractions caused by a $B$ that's not divisible by 2. To do so, first multiply through by $2$. This will not change the solutions since $0=2(Ax^2+Bx+C)$ has the same zeros as $0=Ax^2+Bx+C$. Next, dilate by a scale factor of $2A$ to eliminate the coefficient of $x^2$. For an original equation of $0=Ax^2+Bx+C$, the resulting equation would be $0=x^2+2Bx+4AC$--an even easier quadratic to solve! And all you'd need to do is scale back the solutions by $2A$ at the end!

If something about this seems familiar, it should! Using this equation now DIRECTLY ties to the quadratic formula!

> $m=\frac{-2B}{2}=-B$
>   $d^2=m^2-C=B^2-4AC$
>   $d=\sqrt{B^2-4AC}$
>   $m\pm d=-B\pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}$
>   Scaled back by $2A$, our solutions are $\frac{-B\pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$.

As cool as it would be to stop right here, I think it'd be good to end with this being applied to an actual quadratic. We'll apply it to **$3x^2 + 3x + 1 = 0$** taken from the end of the question. Again, this really is no different than using the quadratic formula, only its now intuitive--we know what all the pieces *mean*.

1. Multiply through by $B$, and dilate using $2A$ as the scale factor by writing a new equation of the form $0=x^2+2Bx+4AC$.

   > $0=x^2+6x+12$
2. Find $m$ and $d$ for this new quadratic.

   > $m=\frac{-6}{2}=-3$
   >   $d^2=(-3)^2-12=-3$
   >   $d=\sqrt{-3}=i\sqrt{3}$
   >   $\frac{m\pm d}{2A}=\frac{-3\pm i\sqrt{3}}{6}$