# quadratic formula derive $ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{align*}
ax^{2} + bx + c = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow 4a^{2}x^{2} + 4abx + 4ac = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (4a^{2}x^{2} + 4abx + b^{2}) = b^{2} - 4ac    \tag{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (2ax + b)^{2} = b^{2} - 4ac\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2ax + b = \pm\sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a}
\end{align*}

how does in step-2 4abx simplified to b. if it is divided by 4ax then it should be on both side.
step-2 can someone explain it in detail?

Comment: In step two: **1** transfer $4ac$ to RHS and add $b^2$ to both sides. **2** Express LHS as a square.

Comment: **Hint:** If you expand $(2ax + b)^2$, then you get
$$(2ax + b)^2 = (2ax)^2 + 2(2ax)b + b^2 = 4a^2 x^2 + 4abx + b^2.$$
@davidritchie: Is this what you meant to ask about?

Comment: Please read the answer provided by Andre Nicolas to the question [Why can ALL quadratic equations be solved by the quadratic formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

The $b$ comes from equating the middle term in the equation: $(2ax + \triangle)^2 = 4a^2x^2 + 4abx + b^2$. So the missing $\triangle$ is the $b$ you are talking about. It's a standard completing square technique in an intermediate algebra course at the college level.

Answer (score 0):

$$
ax^2+bx+c=0\\
$$
Assuming $a\neq 0$, divide by $a$ and complete the square:
$$
(x+b/2a)^2-b^2/4a^2+c/a=0\\
$$
Move everything without $x$ to the right and take the square root:
$$
x+b/2a=\pm\sqrt{{b^2 \over 4a^2}-{c\over a}}\\={\pm 1\over 2a}\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\\
$$
Subtract $b/2a$ from both sides
$$
x={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over 2a}\\
$$