# Why is -(-x), the negation of a negation, not the product of two negations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, arithmetic, integers

I was told that the negation of a negation is not the product of two negations. I understand this to be so because if we prove $-(-x)=x$, we do so using the property of negation:
$x+(-x)+(-(-x))=0$, which would equal $x$ and $-(-x)$. I get this part.

However, we know that $-1x=-x$. So if we think of $-(-x)$ as $-1\times(-1x)$, is this not the product of two negations?

Comment: I would understand "the product of two negations" as $(-x) \cdot (-x)$. Otherwise, this is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: I suppose in formal logic, the negation of a truth $p$ is written as $~p$, the negation of this is back to $p$. If one is considering algebraic quantities then the negative of $x$ is written as $-x$ the negative of this is $(-1)(-1)x = (-1)^2 x = x$

Comment: Use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If $\,n(x):= -x\,$ then $-(-x) = n(n(x)) = \color{#c00}{n^2}(x)\,$ is the *result* of applying the $\rm\color{#c00}{product\ (square)}$ of the negation operation $\,n\,$ (this product = identity operation, i.e. negation is an involution or reflection). Thus it can be viewed as the result of applying a "product" operator $\, n^2 = n\circ n,\,$ where multiplication is *operator (function) composition*  in the associated [operator algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a242%20%22operator%20algebra%22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, yes, $-(-x) = (-1)(-x)$, so in that sense, you could say that $-(-x)$ is the product of two negations.

If you write down the expression $-(-x)$ on a sheet of paper, you haven't written it *as* a product of two negations, because you haven't written a multiplication sign, nor have you used any other kind of notation that denotes multiplication. But, as you know, negating is the same thing as multiplying by $-1$, so there isn't any important difference between $-(-x)$ (which is written without multiplication) and $(-1)(-x)$ (which is written with multiplication).

---

In response to:

> I was under the assumption that the parentheses after the - denote multiplication, but is this a poor way to think about negation?

In this case, no, the parentheses after the negation sign don't denote multiplication. You can denote multiplication by writing two expressions (that is, two sequences of symbols that represent numbers) next to each other. However, the expression $-(-x)$ does not mean $-$ multiplied by $(-x)$, because $-$ is not an expression (that is, $-$ is not a symbol that represents a number).

That said, I think that no, this is not a poor way to think about negation. Negation *is* the same thing as multiplying by $-1$ (even if it's not technically defined that way), so, in my opinion, there's nothing wrong with seeing a negation sign and thinking "that means 'multiply by $-1$.'"

Comment: In fact you *have* written a product, viz. the operator product (composition) of the two negation operations - see my comment on the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque I suppose that's true, but as you know, that's a different meaning of the word "product." I think a precalculus student is likely to only be familiar with the definition of the word "product" as the product of two numbers (and probably the pointwise product of two number-valued functions).

Comment: Most calculus students are already familiar with such operator products, e.g. the  matrix product is [the operator product of the associated linear maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29799/242). Also it is common to work with [differential operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26158/242) when solving differential euqations (and [analogously](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/678917/242) for recurrences = difference equations)

Comment: I was under the assumption that the parentheses after the - denote multiplication, but is this a poor way to think about negation?

Comment: @AmyLee I've added a response to your question to my post.