# Finding the error in this proof that 1=2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, fake-proofs

I have a "proof" that has an error in it and my goal is to figure out what this error is. The proof:

**If $x = y$, then**

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x^2 &=& xy \nonumber \\
x^2 - y^2 &=& xy - y^2 \nonumber \\
(x + y)(x - y) &=& y(x-y) \nonumber \\
x + y &=& y \nonumber \\
2y &=& y \nonumber \\
2 &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}
$$

---

My best guess is that the error starts with the line $2y = y$. If we accept that $x + y = y$ is true, then

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x + y &=& y \\
x &=& y - y \\
x &=& y = 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Did I find the error? If not, am I close?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ When debugging proofs on *abstract* objects, the error may become simpler to spot after specializing to more *concrete* objects. In your proof the symbols $\rm\:x,y\:$ denote abstract numbers, so let's specialize them to concrete numbers, e.g. $\rm\:x = y = 3.\:$ This yields the following "proof"

$$\begin{eqnarray}
3^2 &=& 3\cdot3  \\
3^2 - 3^2 &=& 3\cdot 3 - 3^2  \\
(\color{c00}{3 + 3})\:(\color{c00}{\color{#0a0}{3 - 3}}) &=& \color{c00}3\: (\color{#0a0}{3-3}) \\
\color{#c00}{3 + 3} &=&\color{#c00} 3\ \ {\rm via\ cancel}\ \ \color{#0a0}{3-3}  \\
2\cdot 3 &=& 3  \\
2 &\:=\:& 1
\end{eqnarray}$$

We can find the first false inference by finding the first $\rm\color{#c00}{false\ equation}$ above;  if it is equation number $\rm\: n\!+\!1,\:$ then the inference from equation $\rm\:n\:$ to $\rm\:n\!+\!1\:$ must be incorrect. Doing this above we infer that the culprit is "${\rm via\ cancel}\ \ \color{#0a0}{3-3}$", $ $ i.e. $\,x\cdot \color{#0a0}0 = y\cdot \color{#0a0}0\not\Rightarrow x = y,\,$ i.e. it divided by $\color{#0a0}0$.

Analogous methods prove helpful generally: when studying abstract objects and something is not clear, look at concrete specializations to gain further insight on the general case.

**Remark** $ $ It is however valid to cancel nonzero *polynomials* and then deduce consequences, e.g. if $\,f(x,y)\,$ and $\,g(x,y)\,$ are (formal) polynomials then

$$\begin{align}f(x,y)(x-y) &= g(x,y)(x-y)\\[.2em] \Rightarrow\ \  f(x,y) &= g(x,y)\end{align}\qquad$$

therefore $\,f(a,b) = g(a,b)$ for *all* $a,b\,$ (even if $\,a=b\,$ so $\,x-y = a-b = 0).\,$ For example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98365/242) where the polynomial $f$ is a determinant, and we prove *Sylvester's Determinant Identity* $\rm\ det\:\! (I+AB)=det\:\!(I+BA)\, $ by cancelling $\rm\,det\,A\, $ from $\rm\,det\,$ of $\rm\   (1+AB)A = A(1+B A)$. *Beware* that this slick proof is often wrongly deemed incorrect even by some professors - see the discussion there.

Answer (score 5):

That certainly is an error, although there is an error that precedes it.

**HINT:** Look at all the places you have $(x-y)$ in your proof. What is $x-y$? What are you doing with $x-y$ each time it shows up?

Answer (score 4):

In third line you have written:

> $(x+y)(x-y) = y(x-y)$

Since $x=y$, we can't cancel $(x-y)$, as that equals 0.

Cancellation law in any Integral domain is the following:

> Left cancellation law:  If $a\neq 0$ then $ab= ac$ implies $b=c$.
>
> Right cancellation law:  If $a\neq 0$ then $ba=bc$ implies $b=c$.

Comment: OK let's try this. Because $x=y$, $(x - y) = 0$ which means $(x+y)(x-y) = y(x-y) = 0$? In which case we can just stop there.

Comment: Yes... you can't proceed after the line $(x+y)(x-y)= y(x-y)$ as $x-y$ is zero.

Comment: Also, it took me a minute, but I understand the cancellation laws now. Effectively, cancelling a variable is just dividing both sides by that variable. In this case, where $x-y = 0$, this is not allowed because division by 0 is always undefined. Correct?

Comment: yes exactly.. you can think like this...

Comment: "Cancellation law in any field [..]"; also in any ring: if $a$ is a unit :)

Comment: @J.D.. yes in any ring... thanks.

Comment: (James - FYI "rings, fields, units and zero divisors" are related objects in a field commonly known as "abstract algebra". For when the time comes... :) )

Comment: The Chaz -- I hope the time comes soon. Until very recently I haven't understood why people like the subject so much. I picked up a copy of Spivak's *Calculus 3rd Edition* and I'm falling in love with it -- and I haven't even gotten to the Calculus yet! I've been a member of this Stack Exchange for a couple of days and the insight you guys have provided is just fantastic. Kudos and keep up the good work!

Comment: @PradipMishra Since you didn't add "if $a$ is a unit", you should either add it, or replace "Ring" by integral domain.

Comment: @MTurgeon, yes my mistake.. edited.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already declared:

> $x = y$

∴ $x - y = 0$

On step 3, dividing by $x-y$ ($= 0$) is a mathematical error, since it is mathematically invalid to divide anything by $0$.