# What step is wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the error in a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117998/finding-the-error-in-a-proof)

1. $a=b$
2. $ab=a^2$
3. $ab-b^2=a^2-b^2$
4. $b(a-b)=(a+b)(a-b)$
5. $b= a+b$

Reminder the first step where $b = 2b$
So,

$1=2$

In this case in my opinion the wrong step is that in the third, because you can´t subtract $b^2$ from both sides.

This question it was taken from a math exam.

Comment: I wonder why the most common questions can't be researched on [a search engine] before being asked.

Answer (score 5):

$a=b \implies a-b=0$

from step 4 to 5 you are dividing through by $a-b=0$.

Comment: Where did you see question like this Alex?

Comment: @ViniciusL.Beserra a friend has asked me this before.

Answer (score 4):

You divided by $a-b$ in step 5), which is zero by assumption 1).

Answer (score 4):

The transition from *step 4* to *step 5* is wrong.$$\rm a  = b\qquad\Rightarrow \qquad a - b = 0$$If  $\rm \,a  - b = 0\, $, then $\rm (a + b)(a - b) = b(a  - b) $  can be written as $\rm 0(a + b) = 0b$

While what we do in the transition is, we divide both sides by $0$,  hence breaking the so-called “fundamental rule”: **never divide by zero!**

Comment: Thanks for you commentary.