# Does Little Fermat imply that if $p$ is prime then $x^p=x $ in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z [x] $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences

As in the title, I'm trying to understand the implications of Fermat's Little Theorem in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z [x] $. Fermat states that if $p $ is prime then for all integer $x$, $x^p-x $ is a multiple of $p$. As far as I can see, this should mean that $x^p-x=0$ in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z [x] $, but I'm not sure. Is that correct?

Comment: No, it does not hold for the variable in the polynomial ring, since the statement is for an integer.

Comment: Polynomials and the functions they determine by evaluation should not be confused, especially over finite rings. The former family is infinite, the latter finite.

Comment: @DougM Yeah, I removed my comment and made a new one when I saw you had removed it :)

Comment: @Tobias I see, thank you

Comment: @Richard Note that by the fundamental theorem you might expect this polynomial to have $p$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (since it's of degree $p$), and in fact it does - so it can be written as $\prod_{i=0}^{p-1}(x-i)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Now, from this, can you see how to prove (half of) Wilson's Theorem?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98365/242) for some background on formal polynomials vs. polynomial functions.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Just saw your comment, not really...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *polynomial* $x^p-x$ is *not* the zero polynomial in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z [x]$.

The polynomial *function* $x^p-x$ *is* the zero function $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. That's what Fermat says.

Polynomials and polynomial functions are different objects but they can be identified when the base field is infinite.