# Difference between a function and polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials, finite-fields

This question might be silly and simple, but I'm confused.
Author mentions, let $f(t)\in \mathbb{F}_{q}[t]$ be a function and $h(t)$, a generic polynomial of the form $h(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=m}a_it^i$, where $a_i$  variables over $\mathbb{F}_q$.
What does this mean?
When $a_i$, takes values from $F_q$ does it become a function in $F_q[t]$?
Please help

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98345/11619)

Answer (score 2):

Given field $\mathbb F$ and a symbol $t$, a member of $\mathbb F[t]$  is an expression of the form $\sum_{i=0}^m a_i t^i$, where $a_i \in \mathbb F$. This is a polynomial  over $\mathbb F$, i.e. with coefficients in $\mathbb F$, in the indeterminate $t$, but it is not a *function*.  You get a function associated to the polynomial by specifying
a domain $D$ (perhaps $\mathbb F$, or some algebra over $\mathbb F$), and mapping each $x \in D$ to $\sum_{i=0}^m a_i x^i$.

The distinction between polynomials and polynomial functions may seem artificial when dealing with the real or complex fields, but with finite fields it is important.  For example, the function $x \mapsto x^p - x$ on $\mathbb F_p$ is identically $0$, i.e. $x^p - x = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb F_p$, but the 
polynomial $x^p - x$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ is not the $0$ polynomial.

Comment: Related:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160986/rings-for-which-no-polynomial-induces-the-zero-function

Comment: @Robert, thank you.