# Verifying that a given set is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to show that[image]

I have said:

f=0 is in I so I is non-empty.

Let $f,g$ be members of $I$

$(f+g)(\sqrt5)=f(\sqrt5)+g(\sqrt5)=0+0=0 ==> f+g ∈ I$ so I is closed under addition

Let $g∈Q[x], f ∈ I$

$fg(\sqrt5)=f(\sqrt5)g(\sqrt5)=0*g(\sqrt5)=0 ==> fg ∈ I $ so I closed under multiplication from R.

Is this sufficient to show that I is an ideal?

Comment: Yes, that is it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's rephrase it slightly to gain a little  more insight. Let $\,\ell(f) = f(\sqrt{5})\,$ be the map that evaluates $\,f(x)\,$ at $\,x = \sqrt{5}.\,$ Note that it is a ring hom: $\ \ell(f\pm g) \,=\, \ell f \pm \ell g ,\, $ and $\ \ell(fg) = (\ell f)\,(\ell g).\ $

More generally let $\,\ell \,$ be any ring hom and let $I$ be its kernel, i.e. all $f$ such that $\,\ell f = 0.\,$

Then $\,f,g \in I\,\Rightarrow\, \ell f,\,\ell g=0\,\Rightarrow\ \ell(f\pm g) = \ell f \pm\ell g = 0\pm0 = 0\ \Rightarrow\, f\pm g\in I,\ $ and

further $\ \ell(fh) = \ell f\, (\ell h) = 0\cdot \ell h = 0,\ $ so $\,fh\in I.\,$ Thus the kernel of a ring hom is an ideal.

Likewise, many ideals arise naturally as kernels of ring homomorphisms.

**Remark** $\ $ This raises an important question: why is the evaluation map a ring hom?  Have you proved that yet?  Note that this is not true for *any* ring, since, if so, evaluating $\, ax = xa $ at $\,x = b\,$ shows $\,ab = ba\,$ so the coefficient ring is *commutative*. In fact, this necessary condition is also sufficient for evaluation to be a ring hom. You should prove this at some point, since it helps to understand essential properties of polynomial rings $\,R[x]\,$  (as [universal $R$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4300/242)).

Comment: Does this differ from what I have said?

Comment: @user43290 It is a  generalization - one that will prove very useful in practice.

Comment: @user43290 I added a remark which explains further why I thought it instructive to present it a bit more abstractly.

Answer (score 0):

You've shown it to be closed to multiplication from the ring and to additions.
Can you show it's also an additive subgroup?

Comment: Do I not do this by showing it is non-empty and closed under addition?

Comment: @user43290 is $\mathbb{N}$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$? That being said it is not really necesseray once you know mult closed in addition.

Answer (score 0):

The usual definition of an ideal is that it is an additive subgroup of $R$ stable under multiplication by elements of $R$.

Your first point does not in itself show the first part, as an additively closed subset might not be a subgroup.

It is however possible that you have either an unusual defintion or a lemma that allows for your proof. The point is that by the multiplicative closedness you get additve inverses "for free" as $-g = (-1)g$.

A common criterion to show that something is an ideal is to show for the additive part that $f-g \in I$ for $f,g \in I$; that is using a common criterion for a non-empty subset being a subgroup.